# Behavior with left-shifting int

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following undefined and why?

```
int i = 0xFF;
unsigned int r = i << 24;
```

Comment: I'm sure you could run this up in a debugger in milliseconds ;)

Comment: @DaveRlz that won't tell you if it's undefined.

Comment: Casting `i` to `unsigned` before the shift should work.. I think.

Comment: ¤ On a 32 bit system it is formally **undefined**. C++11 §5.8/2, discussing the expression `E1 << E2`: “if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1×2^E2` is representable
in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.” And with 32 bits the value 0xFF000000 is not representable in the immediate result type, which here is `int`. However, in practice it will be no problem, at least for PC programming (regardless of OS). Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Pubby: it may or may not help. If int is 16-bit, the `(unsigned)` cast won't help because you could shift it at most by 15 positions, not even 16, let alone 24.

Comment: @Pubby's comment is the practical answer for how to get formally well-defined behavior here (on a 32-bit system or better). The `unsigned` types are made for bit level operations. The `signed` types are not made for that.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: however practical it is, if you don't pay attention, the too-big-shift-count UB will bite you sooner than the signed-overflow UB.

Comment: @Alex: I find that comment offensive. You are implying that there is a too big shift count in the question, and that I have not paid attention to that. That is not true, it's just your fantasy.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: I must've missed that part, sorry.

Comment: @Alex: possibly you missed your own usage of the definite article "the", which according to Wikipedia denotes "person(s) or thing(s) already mentioned, under discussion, implied, or familiar)". So to any causal reader you were referring to a "too big shift count" already discussed (no such though). Mixing in phrases such as "you don't pay attention" and "will bite  you", and referring to the practicality as flawed, you create a pretty negative associative impression. I don't care much that I'm adding to it by pointing it out.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: those things had been mentioned prior to my comment, although not elaborated in full in this particular comment thread. And then, don't forget that not everyone is a native speaker, so speech isn't going to be perfect all the time. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour is technically undefined unless the `int` type has more than 32 bits.

From C++11, 5.8/2 (describing an expression `E1 << E2`):

> if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is representable
>   in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The result type of `i << 24` is (signed) `int`; if that has 32 bits or less, then `0xff * 2^24 == 0xff000000` is not representable (the maximum representable 32-bit signed value being `0x7fffffff`), so behaviour is undefined as specified in that clause.

Comment: Is the behavior happen to be defined in C++03?

Comment: @Norman: C++03 doesn't explicity say that it's undefined, but it doesn't define it either (meaning that it is undefined).

Answer (score 2):

According to [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) section **5.8 Shift operators**:

> The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.
>
> ```
>     shift-expression:
>         additive-expression
>         shift-expression << additive-expression
>         shift-expression >> additive-expression
> ```
>
> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand is** negative, or **greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand**.

So my answer? Depends on the number of bits in your left operand (which depends on your system).